# Normalise MySQL fulltext score

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, normalization

I'm doing a pretty standard MySQL `MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)` query. I'm returning the score of each row as column `score`. The problem here is that score can be more than 1, so getting a percentage is tricky (multiplying by 100) due to the fact I can get scores greater than 1. My question is, can I normalise the score column so I get all scores from 0 to 1, but keep them in proportion (for example, a score of 4 would be 1, and a score of 2 would become 0.5, etc, but 4 can be a dynamic upper bound).

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(body) AGAINST ('string') AS score 
FROM home_posts 
WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST ('string')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score in a MySQL `MATCH` is not a percentage and trying to convert it to such would be the completely wrong approach altogether. You can read the math behind it at http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_Algorithms#Full-text_Search

EDIT:
I would try

```
SELECT *, 
    MATCH(body) AGAINST ('string') AS score, 
    (MATCH(body) AGAINST ('string') / maxScore) AS normalisedScore
FROM home_posts, 
    (SELECT MAX(MATCH(body) AGAINST ('string')) AS maxScore 
     FROM home_posts) maxScoreTable
WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST ('string')
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough :-) I understand that getting a percentage from the score is silly. My question was how do I get those scores and turn them into a series of numbers from 0-1 regardless of how big they are, but still keeping original proportion.

Comment: The simple math would be `score / MAX(score)`

Comment: Of course! Thanks for that. Would you be able to post a simple example query just so I can wrap my head around this properly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Added possible solution above. Note I don't have any tables to test this on at the minute and may be slightly off. But it's only the syntax around the `MATCH` that could be wrong. But I think it's right.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I needed. I'll debug it if it needs it :-)

Comment: You need to give the `SELECT` statement in the `FROM` statement an alias too, if I'm not mistaken.