# mysql fulltext boolean search - order by relevancy

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm not getting the desired outcome in my attempts to return results of a fulltext search by relevancy. Here's an actual output query example:

```
SELECT *,
       ((9 * (MATCH(title) AGAINST ('"apple 8"' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) +
        (8 * (MATCH(title) AGAINST ('+apple +8' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) +
        (7 * (MATCH(title) AGAINST ('apple* 8 ' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) +
        (6 * (MATCH(description) AGAINST ('"apple 8"' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) +
        (5 * (MATCH(description) AGAINST ('+apple +8 apple* 8 ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))) as relevance
FROM items
WHERE status='1'
AND ((MATCH(title, description) AGAINST ('"apple 8" +apple +8 apple* 8 ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))
ORDER BY cat_featured DESC
       , relevance DESC
```

I'm sure that's probably all messed up, but I've tried different setups and keep getting the same results... In this example, an item containing both "apple" and "8" in the title is being returned 17th out of 55 results, instead of 1st like I want it to be, as it's the only result that has both of the terms in the title. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but you probably want to group your FULLTEXT search, instead of using load of separate ones. I asked a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417792/normalise-mysql-fulltext-score) which may be of help regarding the relevancy of each row returned.

Comment: Thanks very much for trying to help. Unfortunately, your question didn't make anything clearer for me... I find this stuff incredibly confusing! I did have the matches in just 2 groups at first (1 for title, 1 for description), and was getting the same output, so I've been playing around with it, trying to figure out how to manipulate the order of the results. The first part works (exact matches are returned first). I don't understand how to get results containing both words to come up next.

Comment: There are loads of things that confuse the crap out of me too - you're not alone. Unfortunately, the more advanced features of MySQL is one of those things.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the `(MATCH(xyz) AGAINST('abc'))` with any number is wrong. You cannot do that because they are not the actual numbers.

Read more here [Using MySQL Full-text Searching](http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example doing something similar. Hope this helps.

Before this can work you need to build a FULLTEXT index on those two cols. If you are using phpMyadmin this is pretty easy.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
select *, MATCH(title, description) AGAINST("your string here" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
        from items 
        where
        active = 1 and 
        MATCH(title, description) AGAINST("your string here" IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by relevance desc
```